# When doesn't a differential equation have a solution of the form $Ae^{at}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $x^{''} + x = q(t)$ for a nonzero function . For which of the following q(t) functions does the differential equation NOT have a solution of the form $Ae^{at}$?

$$a) e^t$$
$$b) e^{-t}$$
$$c) e^{it}$$
$$d) e^{-it}$$
$$f) e^{2t}$$
$$g) e^{3t}$$
$$h) 1$$

So the homogeneous solution is found by using the characteristic polynomial and exponentiating its roots. In the end we have: $y_h = c_{1}e^{it} + c_{2}e^{-it}$  where $y_h$ stands for the homogeneous solution.

The answer to the above equation is $q(t) = e^{it} $ and $q(t) = e^{-it}$. Why is this exactly the two terms that make up the homogeneous solution?

Comment: I have the impression that your question is not very precise. For those $q$'s you are in the resonant case and, along with the exponentials, you have particular non-exponential solutions like $te^{it}/2i$.But you do not get exponentials as generic solutions for many other choices of $q$, say for $q(t)$ being a polynomial... Does $q$ have to be an exponential itself?

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to add the answer choices I was given. Yes, it seems that q(t) has to be a polynomial including $e^0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's exactly because $e^{it}$ and $e^{-it}$ are the solutions to the homogeneous solution that this problem arises. Let's assume that $x=e^{at}$ (ignoring $A$ because that's just a multiple that can be multiplied in later). Now, we plug this potential solution into the differential equation with $q(t)=e^{it}$:
$$(a^2+1)e^{at}=e^{it}$$
Now we know that the only possible value for $a$ is $i$, because the exponent on the RHS is $i$. However, when we plug it in on the left, we get that 
$$0=e^{it}$$
which is nonsense. It's **exactly** because $i$ and $-i$ satisfy the characteristic polynomial $a^2+1$ (and hence are solutions for the homogeneous case) that the equation collapses/becomes $0$ on the LHS if the RHS has $q(t)=e^{it}$ or $e^{-it}$.

The solution to this conundrum? Just multiply an extra factor of $t$ in front of the $e^{\pm it}$, so basically you assume the solution is in the from $x=te^{at}$ instead of just $x=e^{at}$

Comment: Thank you! This made a lot of sense!